# Generating functions in a proof

Tags: probability-theory, generating-functions

I'm working at the moment with queues. In a proof of a theorem, there is the following statement:

> > Suppose $G(s)$ is a generating function and we have the following conditions:
> >     $$0<G(0)<1,$$
> >     $$G(1)=1,$$
> >     $$G'(1)>1.$$
> >     Then  there exists a number $b \in (0,1)$ sucht that $G(b)=b.$

There is written, that one should draw a picture and then it is clear... For me that is not so easy, how can I draw a picture with the conditions above? It's impossible for me to think of a drawing. Can anybody help me please?

I would really appreciate any idea or help!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Generating function]

Since $G'(1) > 1$, the generating function must somewhere cross the line $y = x$

Sorry for the ugly picture!!!

edit: i am not familiar with queueing-theory, but i suppose the generating function is on the form $\sum a_nx^n$, i.e. continuous

Comment: Thank you so much!! I understand it! yess u r right! $G(s)=\sum a_n s^n.$  I have a second (small) question. It is given that $G(s)=\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda S (s-1)}]$, where $S$ is a random variable such that $\lambda \mathbb{E}[S]>1.$ From this one can deduce that $0<G(0)<1$. I try to understand this conclusion. So, $G(0)=\mathbb{E}[e^{- \lambda S}]=\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{e^{ \lambda S}}]$ is strictly smaller than $1$, since $e^{ \lambda S}>1$ because $\lambda \mathbb{E}[S]>1.$ Is that right?  But why is it strictly greater than $0$?

Comment: Sorry, i am not familiar with the notation $\mathbb{E}[\cdots]$. You may however accept and up-vote my answer if you'd like!